# change icon on html page upon user action using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am quite a newbie web development having basic knowledge in `HTML CSS` and `JavaScript`. I have a small blog page, which allows users to upvote a title of a blogpost - similar to what SoF has on its questions.

So, the problem I am facing is that I am unsure how I should change the icon (which I have in a sprite) once the user has clicked on it. So, in a nut shell

```
(Page1) icon1.png --> User Clicks --> (Page1) icon2.png
```

where icon1.png and icon2.png are in my `sprites.png`

I think JS is the way to go for this - but I was wondering if it is (is doing some sort of `AJAX` the way to do it?)- any directions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have an onclick event handler in the button. Call a js function to replace the image

Comment: as you are not doing a postback you don't need ajax, just a proper click handler to change the css class name of the sprite container http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @Pete he may not know what jQuery is? `"I am quite a newbie web developer"`...

Comment: a good chance for him to learn then! a lot easier than learning pure js

Comment: @Pete: thanks a lot for your answer - I have started learning JQuery about a week ago - so, I am able to understand what you have said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript as below.

On click set `background` image position.

```
document.getElementById('SELECTOR').style.backgroundPosition='0px 150px';
```

where `SELECTOR` is the `element's ID` on which you want to change image position

As per you said **you have sprite image** so you just need to set image position accordingly.

Comment: thanks for this Dipesh: Quick question: as others have suggested is it possible to do the same in JQuery?

Comment: @user2152572 yes even jQuery can do this easy way and its very easy to understand...

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function(){
    $('#SELECTOR').click(function(){
    $('#icon1').css('background-position','0px, 120px') //whtever bg position
     });
     })
```